# Cannot access activity's property from the dialog

Tags: android, arraylist

I have an activity from which I call the dialog. On positive dialog's event I'm trying to add a custom item form the "showAddPhraseDialog" method to the List (phrasesToSave) which is property of the activity's class.

But the list size do not increases.

Activity class:

```
public class AddActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView rv_select_person;
    private ChildHorizontalAdapter personAdapter;

    private RecyclerView rv_conversation;
    private UnsavedConversationAdapter conversationAdapter;

    private List<UnsavedPhrase> phrasesToSave;
    private List<Child> personsList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        phrasesToSave = new ArrayList<UnsavedPhrase>();

        // conversation widgets
        rv_conversation = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_conversation);
        conversationAdapter = new UnsavedConversationAdapter(phrasesToSave);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(AddActivity.this);
        rv_conversation.setLayoutManager(llm);
        rv_conversation.setAdapter(conversationAdapter);

        ...

    }


    private void showAddPhraseDialog(final Child phrase_author)
    {
        boolean wrapInScrollView = true;
        new MaterialDialog.Builder(AddActivity.this)
                .title(R.string.label_what_was_said)
                .customView(R.layout.dialog_add_phrase, wrapInScrollView)
                .positiveText(R.string.button_add)
                .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {




                        EditText tePhrase = (EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.te_phrase);

                        String phrase_text = tePhrase.getText().toString();

                        if (!StringUtils.isNullAndEmpty(phrase_text)) {

                            UnsavedPhrase new_phrase = new UnsavedPhrase(phrase_text, phrase_author);

                            phrasesToSave.add(new_phrase);

                        }


                    }
                })
                .show();
    }

}
```

Comment: First check if its going in your If  condition then AddActivity.this.phrasesToSave.add(new_phrase);

Comment: Yes it's fired. I've posted the short piece of code here. That's strange for me...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late reply You forgot to notify the adapter

```
if(conversationAdapter != null)
{
  conversationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Checked, the check is passed correctly. It's a strange behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug and check that after the **phrasesToSave.add(new_phrase);** the list has one new element in it. If it has a new  element, but you don't see the element in your UI, you should notify the RecyclerView that it's data set has changed. Try calling **notifyDataSetChanged()**. [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) for it.

Your code looks fine. If there isn't a new element in **phrasesToSave** after the **add**, then try to clean your project. **Build -> Clean Project**